# extra white space in an Imported .mov

Tags: animation

I can creat a .mov file and the nb where I Import|Animation, the same .mov.  The animation plays in Mathematica, but comes in with a white background that is about 2x as large as required.
Can I use some control to resize just this background?  It seems to defy cropping.

(Couldn't find a way to attach the two for comparison)
Charlie

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing this.  Can you paste some of your code?

Comment: The only code is: Import["filepath.mov", "Animation"]

Comment: Is there any way I could reply to you with attached .mov and .nb files?